# Function of two variables: Do symmetry tests exist?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, symmetry

let's assume we are working with the function:

z=e<sup>-x<sup>2</sup>-y<sup>2</sup></sup>

Plotting this function shows that there is a (global) maximum at (x, y) = (0, 0).

The plot clearly shows some sort of symmetry to the coordinate origin. Is there a correct term to describe this symmetry and more importantly, is there a way to check (analytically) whether a function of two variables has any symmetries?

Thankful for any input.

Comment: what do you mean by symmetry? Do you want to have $f(x,y) = f(+/- x,+/-y)$ for any pair $x,y$ and any choice of signs?

Comment: Hint: the distance to the origin (aka radius) is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and your function depends only on the square of that. Rotational symmetry.

Comment: Or maybe you want to have $f(T(x,y)) = f(x,y)$ for any linear isometry $T$ ?

Comment: The last statement (with the isometry) is equivalent to saying that $f(x,y) = f(x',y')$ for all $x, y, x', y'$ such that $||(x,y)|| = ||(x',y')||$ (euclidean norm).